# (Discord Bot) on_raw_reaction_add(payload) problem (Ticket System)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey I'm developing a Discord Bot with Python. Here is the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

This program should create text channel in specified category when user reacts to a message. The problem is:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload, ctx):
        message_id = payload.message_id
        if message_id == 700856935012106281:
                guild_id = payload.guild_id
                discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
                if payload.emoji.name == 'koperta':
                        print("zlotek")
                        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
                        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
                        user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
                        emoji = client.get_emoji(700845595103068211)
                        await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)
                        name = '✅ OPENED TICKETS ✅'
                        category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
                        guild = ctx.guild
                        overwrites = overwrites = {
                        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
                        }
                        await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-0001', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```

I get the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_raw_reaction_add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It says it's missing the `ctx` positional argument. Have you tried adding it? Or maybe the function shouldn't have a `ctx` positional argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`on_raw_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) only takes one argument, `payload`

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
        message_id = payload.message_id
        if message_id == 700856935012106281:
                guild_id = payload.guild_id
                guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
                if payload.emoji.name == 'koperta':
                        print("zlotek")
                        channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
                        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
                        user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
                        emoji = client.get_emoji(700845595103068211)
                        await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)
                        name = '✅ OPENED TICKETS ✅'
                        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name=name)
                        overwrites = overwrites = {
                        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
                        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
                        }
                        await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-0001', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have versions of Patrick Haugh code using "return early pattern". making your program more readable.
`on_raw_reaction_add()` only takes 1 argument as written before, unless you use it in class, then 'self' is added
`on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload)`, same for `on_raw_reaction_remove()`.

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    if not message_id == 700856935012106281:
        return

    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

    if payload.emoji.name != 'koperta':
        return

    print("zlotek")

    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    user = client.get_user(payload.user_id)
    emoji = client.get_emoji(700845595103068211)

    if message:
        await message.remove_reaction(emoji, user)

    name = '✅ OPENED TICKETS ✅'
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name=name)
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-0001', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
```

Answer (score 0):

The on_raw_reaction_add event only takes one parameter, "payload" you cannot use ctx in this event, you can resolve the error by removing ctx from the parameters.